# how to export and import stored procedures from phpmyadmin

Tags: php, stored-procedures, import, phpmyadmin, export

Can you guys help me out regarding stored procedures. When I export stored procedure from phpmyadmin, It given as

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `c4mo_get_cities_prc`(IN `p_state_code` VARCHAR(3), IN `p_country_code` VARCHAR(3), IN `p_language_code` VARCHAR(3))
    NO SQL
BEGIN

SELECT city_name, city_code
FROM `c4mo_cities` 
WHERE enabled = 'Y' 
AND language_code = p_language_code
AND state_code = p_state_code
AND country_code = p_country_code;

END
```

And when I import it from phpmyadmin, it giving error as

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 13
```

Comment: Did you set `DELIMITER`?

Comment: What phpMyAdmin version are you using and how are you generating the export? If I go to the Routines tab and press Export, this is not the code that's generated; are you doing something differently from me?

Answer (score 5):

Copy the exported stored procedure to file e.g. myprocedure.sql.
Now modify that .sql file with following:
1) Remove DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
2) At the beginning of stored procedure add delimiter definition.
and at the end reset delimiter.

e.g.

```
`DELIMITER $$
`CREATE  PROCEDURE `c4mo_get_cities_prc`(IN `p_state_code` VARCHAR(3), IN 
`p_country_code` VARCHAR(3), IN `p_language_code` VARCHAR(3))
NO SQL
BEGIN

SELECT city_name, city_code
FROM `c4mo_cities` 
WHERE enabled = 'Y' 
AND language_code = p_language_code
AND state_code = p_state_code
AND country_code = p_country_code;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

After that import stored procedure just like any other database you import by selecting .sql file.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It quite simple if you use phpmyadmin interface.

**For export**:

You will see a routine tab as this tab will be shown only when  you will already have at least one stored procedure.

Just Click on routines tab and you will see your made stored procedure(For the db , you have made).

At below, tick check all on check Box and then export , You just need to copy the whole code and save it to anywhere on your local machine with `your_stored_procedure.sql` file.

**For import:**

Just select the database and import your stored procedure `your_stored_procedure.sql` file as mentioned above, as you generally import .sql file(tables) for your db.

Answer (score 1):

Remove DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`

in local while import,

it will execute.